# Retrieve and download signed document with Digital Certificate to a local system

Tags: docusignapi

I use REST API/Java/XML for template-based embedded signing. After successful signing, I retrieve and download a document similar to API Walkthrough 06. It works fine if there is no Digital Certificate required from Signer; when opened in PDF Reader, all signatures are valid. However, we have to require DocuSign Express Digital Signature (changed Signer’s Identity to DocuSign Express in the template). In this case retrieving the file(s) by the same application and then opening it in PDF Reader leads to “Error during signature verification. Signature contains incorrect, unrecognized, corrupted or suspicious data” when clicked on the blue padlock.” When the same digitally signed document is downloaded from the DocuSign web console, all signatures are valid.
I tried to download the document itself and the certificate separately as an Envelope Document List: {baseURL}/envelopes/{ envelopeId}/documents;
as a combined document without Certificate included: {baseURL}/envelopes/{ envelopeId}/documents/combined;
as a combined document with Certificate included: {baseURL}/envelopes/{ envelopeId}/documents/combined?certificate=true".

The result is the same: “Signature invalid, data error”

What should be changed in the application or Preference settings to avoid "breaking" the digital signature in the resulting PDF file?

Comment: This came up last week and is actively being looked into by the DocuSign Digital Certificates team.

Answer (score 0):

To download documents and preserve digital signatures, you must retrieve signed documents individually with the "combined" parameter explicitly set to "false".

`{baseUrl}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}?combined=false`

Combining documents leads to digital signatures being removed (and it seems in your case they are corrupted). If that doesn't work, try sending exactly one document at a time and use the same URL above as:

`{baseUrl}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/1?combined=false`